# What does "it" in "ordering it" refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *[Braveheart (1995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braveheart)*, Robert meets Leper, who isolated in his disfiguration:

> Robert: A rebellion has begun.
>
> Leper: Under whom?
>
> Robert: A commoner named William Wallace.
>
> Leper: You will embrace this rebellion. Support it from our lands in
> the north.  I will gain English favor by condemning it and ordering **it**
> opposed from our  lands in the south.

What does "it" in "ordering it" refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same as all other "it"s in the sentence - the aforementioned rebellion.

You might be confused by the somewhat unusual structure in "ordering it opposed" - it simply means that Leper intends to order someone (presumably the troops in the southern lands) to oppose the rebellion.

Answer (score 0):

The 'it' also refers to the rebellion.

This passage is slightly archaic in my opinion. It would probably be written as "ordering it to be opposed" in a more modern style. Basically, he is saying he will condemn the rebellion and issue orders that the rebellion must be opposed.